# Why Ubuntu 12.10 displays launcher icons in different size, but 12.04 displays them in the same size?

Tags: 12.04, unity, 12.10, launcher, icons

On Ubuntu 12.10, the launcher icons are displayed in different size in Unity:

[image]

But on Ubuntu 12.04, they are all rendered nicely to the same size:

[image]

Is it a bug in Ubuntu 12.10? How can I change the settings to make Ubuntu 12.10 to render the launcher icons to the same size?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add pictures, just upload them to a site like imgur, link to them in a comment, and a higher rep user can edit them in for you.